# Tensorflow not recognising numbers in a list correctly

Tags: python, list, tensorflow

Hi I'm encountering a problem where Tensorflow does not like the numbers I've selected for the training data. I've borrowed the code from the Tensorflow 'Getting started' tutorial but I have subsituted the `x_train` and `y_train` data list of coordinates with another.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=tf.float32)
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y)) # sum of the squares
# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
# training data
x_train = [1.0,  1.5  ,3.0,   6.0, 8.0, 9.0,   11.0,  12.0,38.0  ,41.0, 82.0]
y_train = [9.5,10.75,14.5,22.0,27.0,29.5,34.5,37,102.0,109.5,212.0]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
#print(sess.run(init))
for i in range(1000):
  sess.run(train, {x:x_train, y:y_train})

# evaluate training accuracy
curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss], {x:x_train, y:y_train})
print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
```

Now the code outputs `Nan` for those values in the lists `x_train` and `y_train`. The original `x_train` and `y_train` data for which it works is

```
x_train = [1,2,3,4]
y_train = [0,-1,-2,-3]
```

EDIT: I'm expecting the value of `W` and `b` to converge to 2.5 and 7.0 respectively.

Comment: so there's no error? But the NaN values for current values for `W`, `b`and `loss` (I'm assuming) are causing you a headache?

Comment: not sure if this makes a difference but you only have `int` values in the working lists and mixed values as well as extra white-space characters in the lists that don't work... you could try making both `numpy.array` formats and specify the data type...

Comment: @Chris as he has declared the variables as floats, tensorflow will cast them to that dtype even if they look like `ints`

Comment: @Chris I added those white spaces to make it clearer the x value that correspond with the y values in the training data. I don't think the issue is in the white spaces.

Comment: @DiegoAgher yup I'm not sure why I'm getting NaN values for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the learning rate of the optimizer. Since you have change the inputs to some arrays with a very different scale, the appropriate learning rate for the model is different. You can avoid this sort of problem using some normalization technique on your input, but in this case you can just tune the learning rate until you find the right value. After a couple of tests, I found that in your case something like 1e-5 should work:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-5)
```

More generally, the problem in this case is that your inputs are quite unevenly distributed. Most of the examples are below 40, but then you have a couple around 100 and one over 200; these last three will have a way bigger impact in the training updates than all the others, so, for example, if there is some noise in one of them, it will have a large effect in the whole model.

Comment: Thanks! Modifying the learning rate has solved the issue. I will keep this in mind for the future.